# How can I refer to two separate ranges?

Tags: excel, vba

Essentially I'm trying to use two columns that aren't next to each other as the data source for a chart. I've set range1 (e.g. A1:A10) and range2 (e.g. C1:C10). The chart is working and correct ranges are being used, but its treating it as one complete range and including the columns between them. How can I tell it to look at them separately?

```
Dim range1 as Range
Dim range2 as Range

Set range 1 = Range("A1:A10")
Set range 2 = Range("C1:C10")

ActiveChart.SetSourceData Source:=Range(range1, range2)
```

Thanks

Comment: Try:  `:=Union(range1, range2)`

Comment: @RonRosenfeld perfect thank you!